# Distinct values on main table left join with another table

Tags: left-join, distinct

Scenario, i have a main table with duplicate records created by deviceID, which i'm trying to dedup by selecting distinct record without device id
To be join with catalog table to have the associated values link via [id] column on both table *(not taking all the attributes)*

Been trying to run below query, it doesn't complete but just times out. Anything wrong with query ?

main table:
{[deviceID],[id],[gaDate],[eolDate],[eosDate],[stage],[lifeCycleConfidence],[eolSupportStage],[eosSupportStage]}

catalog table:
{[fullname],[softwareType],[productName],[publisher],[edition],[marketVersion],[version],[fullname], ..........}

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[main table].[id],
[catalog table].[fullname],
[main table].[gaDate],
[main table].[eolDate],
[main table].[eosDate],
[main table].[stage],
[main table].[lifeCycleConfidence],
[main table].[eolSupportStage],
[main table].[eosSupportStage],
[catalog table].[softwareType],
[catalog table].[productName],
[catalog table].[publisher],
[catalog table].[edition],
[catalog table].[marketVersion],
[catalog table].[version],
[catalog table].[fullname]


FROM [main table]
left join [catalog table] 
on [main table].[id] = [catalog table].[id]
```